# Python: Error when trying to iterate through a list and print values that are positive only

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, typeerror

Disclaimer: I'm new to python

My code:

```
lst = []
def func():

    n = int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        value = int(input())
        lst.append([value])

    return lst

print(func())

limit = 0
x = [i for i in lst if i > limit]
print(x)
```

Basically I want to iterate over the list I've created and print out the another list that only shows the positive values in that list.

I've tried to embed the problem in the function but I still get a similar problem.

Error is:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: `lst.append([value])` is adding a list to your list. Try `lst.append(value)` (without the square brackets). Then you'll have a list of values rather than a list of lists.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Peter.

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
def filter_values(L,limit):
    return [x for x in L if x > limit]
```

Example :

```
In[1]: L=[0,-1,3,4]
lim = 0
filter_values(L,lim)
Out[2]:
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`lst.append([value])` is adding a list to your list. Try `lst.append(value)` (without the square brackets). Then you'll have a list of values rather than a list of lists.